# Selecting block of code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a keyboard shortcut or an extension that would allow me to select a block of code?

I'd like to select everything between curly braces, between HTML tags, etc.

Comment: Are these the best answers for this question in 2019?

Comment: @Mario You're right. I've changed the accepted answer to one that uses native feature.

Comment: Note that this question can be somewhat confusing because block selection, which has long been a feature of many editors is a way to select a rectangle of characters. This question shows up when you search for block selection in VS Code. You can do that with Alt+Shift+Arrows in VS or Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Arrows in VS Code. This question is about selecting blocks of code in the sense of scopes like literals, braced blocks, functions, classes, etc. which VS allows to select with Alt+Shift+Left/Right Arrows.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### For MacOS

On Mac <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to expand the selection. Press multiple times to expand to the block.

Comment: "Press multiple times to expand to the block." is the key :) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Make sure your cursor is inside the containing tags, like right after the closing of the beginning tag...

Comment: If you don't want braces/parenthesis/quotes/etc to be selected as part of the block, set `Text Editor > Auto Surround` to `never` in your settings (`"editor.autoSurround": "never"`)

Answer (score 72):

### For Windows/Linux

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to expand the selection between braces or tags.

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to shrink the selection between braces or tags.

Here is the [Microsoft Visual C++ shortcuts cheatsheet](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) that might help you.

**Update 2019/3:** this inner functionality of Visual Studio is not working very well after some updates. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> now selects things **including braces** (which annoys me).

It is not like its behavior before. It selected things **between curly braces**, when I first posted this answer. I'm using Mark's answer now.

If anyone has a better solution (without an extension) now, please leave a comment.

Comment: Use alt + shift + → to expand selection between braces or tags. Then, while keep holding alt + shift. click →  again several times to append test from the left side of the braces until the function name as part of the same selection. 

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 10):

A real working solution:

Press Command + P and search for `Select to Bracket`
[image: Command P Select to Bracket]

To bind it to a key, press the little Settings icon on the right. The "Keyboard Shortcuts" Window will appear as shown in the image. Double-click on `Select to Bracket` and press a Keyboard shortcut you like, for example `Command + Shift + H`.
[image: Keyboard Shortcuts Select to Bracket]

Now, whenever you want to select code in a block, put your cursor inside the block and press your shortcut.
It is like magic.
[image: Example of Select to Bracket]

Comment: It would be great being able to do it the Eclipse way - by double clicking inside a section block.

Answer (score 8):

Try [the expand-region extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region). It currently works for JavaScript and HTML. To select ever-increasing or decreasing scope.

Answer (score 7):

A quicker way is selecting a line then expanding the selection like this:

1. Select line 
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
2. Expand selection 
   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

Doing this inside a block (HTML element, JavaScript curly braces) will select the inner block (HTML element content, inside curly braces). Do step 2 again to select block including the container (HTML element, whole function, class, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio Code, there is a new option called **Balance**. First you can place the cursor in a suitable block. After that, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. Type *balance* and it lists like below.

[image]

Now press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will select the related code block like below.
For simple use, you can add a shortcut key binding.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this only works with HTML tags, not for expressions in parentheses or braces.

Answer (score 3):

[`⌃⇧⌘← or ⌃⇧⌘→`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_shrink-expand-selection)is also useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

A real working solution:

Search for `Select to Bracket` and bind it to whatever keys you like.

It is like magic.

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on *"bind it to whatever keys"*? For example, instructions and/or a reference on how to do it. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen OK, I posted a new answer, is it the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java in Visual Studio Code and you don't want your block selection to include the brackets (or any other peripheral character) then do the following:

- Go to Visual Studio Code settings by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>.
- Search for "Java selection range" and deselect it.