# How do I select a block of code in VSCode using only the keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the best way to select a block of code in VSCode?

Is there any shortCut, which we can use?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956653/selecting-block-of-code-in-vs-code/50036560#50036560  for expanding a selection to a block of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting block of code in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956653/selecting-block-of-code-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got this by now, but what you need to do is search the Keyboard Shortcuts for the `shift+alt+arrow` mappings, and swap the `cursorColumnSelect` commands (currently mapped to `ctrl+shift+alt+arrow`) with the commands that are currently mapped to the desired keys.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language, it was already asked btw.
[Check this, works with HTML and JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956653/selecting-block-of-code-in-vs-code)

Also pressing Ctrl + I + up/down arrow will select the whole next line.

Answer (score -1):

You can press `SHIFT` and select code with arrow keys.