# VSCode shortcut to select the block of code between two brackets/parentheses?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut which selects the block of code between two parentheses or brackets or squarebrackets compared to the cursor position.

Example:

```
const object = {
  ifTheCursorIs: 'anywhere between the bracket above',
  andTheBracketBelow: 'it should select all everything between them',
}

//so if I press the shortcut, then press backspace,
const object = {}
//should remain
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this post is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50036560/7351272

For mac users, the short answer is:

Use `ctrl` + `shift` + `→` to expand selection between braces or tags,

Use `ctrl` + `shift` + `←` to shrink selection between braces or tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) plugin in vscode. Then you can use `vi(`, `vi{`, `vi[` to select the content in encapsulating first, second and third bracket accordingly. You can also use `yi(`, `yi{`, `yi[` to copy and `ci(`, `ci{`, `ci[` to cut the content in encapsulating first, second and third bracket accordingly.