# Visual studio code ctrl+f until end of a function?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently started using VSC. I use the ctrl+f feature a lot to search for code within a file (please let me know if there's a better feature to do this in VSC), and often times, I only want to search within a particular function in that file, where the function could be a long one (~ 1000 lines). Is there a way to set the ctrl+f stopping criteria to end at the end of the function in that particular file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Find in Selection" feature in VS Code's search bar.

1. Select the entire function you wish to perform search ([This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50036560/11067496) shows how to select a block of code via shortcuts)
2. Toggle the "Find in Selection" button

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Great. I wasn't aware of this feature. Do you know if it's also possible to have your ctrl+f start at where your cursor is located and then end at the corresponding function end line? This way, I won't have to find the end of the function myself :)

Comment: Sorry I'm not too sure if VS Code has this feature...